# Javascript function- transform from one data structure to another

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, data-structures

I'm trying to build a JS function to convert the data structure in the form of 
 'start' to the form of 'expected'.

Using JS `map()` method, how would I do this for the following associative array-

```
const start = {
  Clients: {
    171: { id: 171, name: 'John Smith', active: false },
    172: { id: 172, name: 'Jacob Jacobson', active: true },
    1441: { id: 1441, name: 'Eric Ericsson', active: true },
  },
  Caregivers: {
    1: { id: 1, name: 'John Johnson', active: true },
    37: { id: 37, name: 'James Jameson', active: false },
    15: { id: 15, name: 'Aaron Aaronson', active: true },
  },
  Doctors: {
    1147: { id: 1147, name: 'Doc Docson', active: true },
  },
  Hospitals: {
    115: { id: 115, active: false, name: "St. Mary's" },
  },
  Applicants: {
    17345: { id: 17345, name: 'Bob Bobson', active: true },
    17346: { id: 17346, name: 'Jeff Jeffson', active: false },
    17347: { id: 17347, name: 'Frank Frankson', active: true },
    17348: { id: 17348, name: 'Bill Billson', active: true },
  },
};
```

needs to be converted to-

```
const expected = [
  { label: 'Bill Billson', value: 17348, group: 'Applicants' },
  { label: 'Bob Bobson', value: 17345, group: 'Applicants' },
  { label: 'Frank Frankson', value: 17347, group: 'Applicants' },
  { label: 'Aaron Aaronson', value: 15, group: 'Caregivers' },
  { label: 'John Johnson', value: 1, group: 'Caregivers' },
  { label: 'Eric Ericsson', value: 1441, group: 'Clients' },
  { label: 'Jacob Jacobson', value: 172, group: 'Clients' },
  { label: 'Doc Docson', value: 1147, group: 'Doctors' },
];
```

Comment: Firstly, you can't use map with an Object. Secondly, this is not your personal army.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.map()` can't be used directly on Objects; instead you'll need to use `Object.keys`

```js
const start = {
    Clients: {
        171: { id: 171, name: 'John Smith', active: false },
        172: { id: 172, name: 'Jacob Jacobson', active: true },
        1441: { id: 1441, name: 'Eric Ericsson', active: true }
    },
    Caregivers: {
        1: { id: 1, name: 'John Johnson', active: true },
        37: { id: 37, name: 'James Jameson', active: false },
        15: { id: 15, name: 'Aaron Aaronson', active: true }
    },
    Doctors: {
        1147: { id: 1147, name: 'Doc Docson', active: true }
    },
    Hospitals: {
        115: { id: 115, active: false, name: "St. Mary's" }
    },
    Applicants: {
        17345: { id: 17345, name: 'Bob Bobson', active: true },
        17346: { id: 17346, name: 'Jeff Jeffson', active: false },
        17347: { id: 17347, name: 'Frank Frankson', active: true },
        17348: { id: 17348, name: 'Bill Billson', active: true }
    }
};

// Get an array of properties in 'start'
//   then use Array.reduce() to loop over each item 
const expected = Object.keys(start).reduce( (res, gKey) => {

    // gKey = 'group' name
    // gVal = 'group' value
    let gVal = start[gKey];
    
    // loop over each item in the 'group'
    Object.keys(gVal).forEach(iKey => {
    
        // iKey = 'group.item' name
        // iVal = 'group.item' value
        let iVal = gVal[iKey];
        
        // if the value's .active property is truthy
        if (iVal.active) {
        
            // format the result as desired and add it to the result array
            res.push({
                label: iVal.name,
                value: iKey,
                group: gKey
            });
        }
    });
    
    // return the result array
    return res;
    
// start the .reduce() with an empty array
}, []);
console.log(expected);
```

Answer (score 0):

To loop over an object, you can either use a for ... in loop, or use Object.keys to get an array of keys. For ... in will include inherited properties, so you may need to manually filter them out. Object.keys only returns own properties, so there's no need to do the filtering (but it also isn't appropriate if you need inherited properties)

Example with for ... in:

```
for (var prop in start) {
    if (start.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        // logs out 'Clients', then 'Caregivers', then 'Doctors', then 'Hospitals', then 'Applicants'
        console.log(prop);
    }
}
```

Example with Object.keys:

```
//produces array ['Clients', 'Caregivers', 'Doctors', 'Hospitals', 'Applicants']
var keys = Object.keys(start);
```

So if you wanted to use `.map`, you can start with this, and fill it in to do whatever you desire:

```
Object.keys(start)
    .map(key => {
        //do something with start[key]
        //perhaps you could get Object.keys(start[key]) and loop over that as well.
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution without 'forEach':

```js
function transform(data) {
    Object.entries(data).map(item => Object.values(item[1])
    .map(i => i.group = item[0]))
    .reduce(( acc, cur ) => acc.concat(cur), [])
    .filter(item => item.active === true)
    .sort((a, b) => a.group - b.group)
    .map(item => {
      let expected = {};
      expected.label = item.name;
      expected.value = item.id;
      expected.group = item.group;
    });
   
    return expected;
}
```